# count the number of times a value in a field appears in another field

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have had some great help recently in counting the number of times a value is repeated in a field but my next step is to count how many times a value is repeated in a field ($1) based on the value in another field ($3) with the result at the end of the line such as the example below:

Input File
    1,2,3
    1,1,1
    3,2,3
    4,1,4
    2,1,3
    5,2,2
    5,1,5
    5,4,6

Output File

```
1,2,3,1    
1,1,1,2    
3,2,3,1    
4,1,4,1    
2,1,3,1    
5,2,2,1    
5,1,5,3    
5,4,6,0
```

I am looking at doing this with awk if possible but happy any other suggestion.

Comment: Could you clarify this `how many times a value is repeated in a field ($1) based on the value in another field ($3)` ? I cannot understand what you mean...

Comment: I'm with @user828193, I've no idea what you're trying to do. I thought I did but then your expected output is nothing like I'd have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { a[$1]++; next } { print $0, ($3 in a ? a[$3] : "0") }' OFS=, file file
```

Results:

```
1,2,3,1
1,1,1,2
3,2,3,1
4,1,4,1
2,1,3,1
5,2,2,1
5,1,5,3
5,4,6,0
```

Explanation:

```
FNR==NR { ... }   # for the first file in the arguments list

a[$1]++           # add column one to an array incrementing it's value.

next              # skip processing the rest of the code

{ ... }           # for every line in the second file in the arguments list

print $0          # print the line

($3 in a ? a[$3] : "0")    # ...followed by the value of the third field in the
                           # array if it is indeed in the array, else print "0".
                           # this is a ternary operator, much like an if/else 
                           # statement
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Wish I could give you more than +1 for figuring that one out!

Comment: No need for the ternary expression, just do `print $0, a[$3]+0`.

Comment: Thanks Ed - I wish I'd remember to implement that trick. I totally agree; the requirements were VERY difficult to understand and could have been much better worded.

Comment: sorry if it is confusing, if I take the first line in the input file. in the 3rd column there is a value of 3 and I would like to know how many times 3 appears in the 1st column of the input file which is a result of 1, how when we get to line 2 we have a value of 1 in the 3rd column which is seen 2 times in column 1 and so forth. These results are then added to each line. Does that make sense ? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @kbiles: Yes, that's a quite a bit better. Don't forget to accept the solution if it has worked for you. Or hasn't it? If not, why?